# Checking if two sets of numbers are equal error

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
```

which is referring to this line in the code `if(x[k]==y[j])`

```
Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);        
    int [] x;
    int [] y;
    int size;
    System.out.println("Numbers in launch code sequence should be entered on ");
    System.out.println("single line, separated by blanks.");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Enter length of launch code sequence: ");        
    size = sc1.nextInt();
    x = new int[size];
    y = new int[size];
    int k = 0;
    int j = 0;
    System.out.println("Mr. President, Enter the launch code sequence: ");
    for(;k<x.length; k++){         
    x[k] = sc1.nextInt();}
    System.out.println("Mr. Vice President, Enter the launch code sequence");
    for(;j<y.length; j++){
    y[j] = sc1.nextInt();      
            if(x[k]==y[j]){
                System.out.println("All equal: Missile system cleared for launch.");

            if(x[k]!=y[j]){
                System.out.println("Codes do not check out. Abort missile launch.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At line code --> if(x[k]==y[j]){ 
your k already reached x.length, so it's out of bounds.

Comment: Proper indentation helps to understand the control flow of your code. If you format it correctly, you will surely spot the error yourself.

Comment: I hope that code won't launch actual missiles due to some bug, and cause the end of life as we know it. That would really ruin my day.

Comment: try printing the values of variables or debugging the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code

- iterates through the x Array; afterwards, k == x.length
- iterates through the y Array; inside this iteration, you compare with x[k], which is out of bounds for x

I guess what you *really* want to do is two nested loops - in that case, change

```
  for(;k<x.length; k++){         
    x[k] = sc1.nextInt();}
```

to

```
for(;k<x.length; k++){         
    x[k] = sc1.nextInt();
```

and add the closing `}` after the y loop.

Comment: Thank you very much. This got me one step closer to the end product. It no longer gives me an error message. My only problem now is if I enter 2 sets of number with 1 set having a different number than the other, it still says that they are equal sets! What can I do?

Comment: You're printing the "all are equal" message every time a single *character* is matching. I suggest you set a "not matching" flag instead if you encounter a wrong character, and after the loops, you print a single message telling the user whether the match was successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

At this stage

```
if(x[k]==y[j]){
```

`k` has finished iterating through its array and will be set to `x.length`

and therefore out of bounds

Answer (score 0):

You should reset the value of `k` back to `0` after you've done loading the code. Or you can just define it in the loop header.

```
for(int k = 0; k < x.length; k++)
{
    // Your code here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After this for loop finishes :

```
for(;k<x.length; k++){         
    x[k] = sc1.nextInt();}
```

value of k will be x.length

```
k == x.length //will be true. because the k will be incremented and the condition k<x.length will be checked. this is how the for loop functions
```

and in the next for loop you are accessing

```
x[k] // equivlent of  x[x.length] which is out of abounds
```

The maximum index that you are allowed to access is `x[x.length-1]` because in java arrays the indexing starts from 0

Hence the Exception ArrayIndexOutofBounds,  x[k] will be out of bounds